# What is the purpose of flat_map in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to understand why the `flat_map` function is necessary in Tensorflow. When I consider the following code:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
ds = ds.window(5,shift=1,drop_remainder=True)
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda window :window.batch(10))
for x in ds:
    print(x)
```

I get the following output:

```
tf.Tensor([0 1 2 3 4], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([1 2 3 4 5], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([2 3 4 5 6], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([3 4 5 6 7], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([4 5 6 7 8], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)
tf.Tensor([5 6 7 8 9], shape=(5,), dtype=int64)
```

This seems reasonable, but I would've thought the `window` function would be sufficient. Instead, if I rely only on the window function, like so:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.range(10)
ds = ds.window(5,shift=1,drop_remainder=True)
for x in ds:
    print(x)
```

I get this:

```
<_VariantDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)>
<_VariantDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)>
<_VariantDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)>
<_VariantDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)>
<_VariantDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)>
<_VariantDataset element_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name=None)>
```

Why do I need a VariantDataset? Why doesn't the window function automatically produce the output I get after applying the `flat_map` function? I feel like the Tensorflow developers want to allow for other possibilities, or situations, but I can't imagine what they are. What situation would be helped/prevented by the VariantDatasets?

Comment: In essence, flat_map proves indispensable as it facilitates the application of a function to individual elements (like each window dataset), subsequently amalgamating the results into a unified dataset. Devoid of it, one would solely iterate over the dataset objects rather than the elements enclosed within.

When flat_map isn't employed, TensorFlow resorts to **VariantDataset** as an intermediary stage to encapsulate the dataset of datasets engendered by the window function. However, it doesn't directly grant access to the elements nested within each window.